# Can I remove the pulsing XFCE logo on logon in Xubuntu 11.10?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

On Xubuntu 11.10, when I log in, the XFCE mouse pulses in front of a white-grey screen for a few seconds as everything starts up. Is there a way to remove this, or replace it with something else? Even something hacky like editing the image png to be the same as its background is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Settings Managaer (accessible from the menu with the XFCE logo as button), go to "Session and Startup".  Then click on the "Splash" tab.  Select the "none" option along the left.  Right now you should have some other option like "Mice" selected.